# Iterate over folder with images and put names into a .csv

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I am trying out the google vision API & for that I want to do some preparations. I have collected some images online with which I want to work with.
There are around 100 images and now I want to set up a .csv file where the first column has the names of the images inside, so that I can later go over them.

Example:

Name

Picture1.jpg

Picture2.jpg

etc.

Does someone know a Python way to achieve this? So that I can run the code and it puts those names into a .csv?

Thanks already and have a good one!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `glob` in python to iterate on all the images in a directory and write the image names to a csv file.
Example:

```
import glob
import os

f = open('images.csv', 'w')

for file in glob.glob('*.png'):
    f.write(os.path.basename(file))

f.close()
```

Comment: Close the file object. `f.close()`